# AMPscript can't declare a variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, html

I've been trying to print the product rows from a DE in a digital receipt email. Everything works fine unless I want to declare the variables. So the code underneath works perfectly if I remove the 

`var @lookupValue.`

When I try to initialize the vars @productName, @productPrice in the for-loop, I get the same issue.

Full code:

```
%%[
var @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = FirstName 

set @numRowsToReturn = 0 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("TESTDE",@numRowsToReturn,"ProductPrice asc","FirstName", @lookupValue)

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) 
    set @productName = field(@row,"ProductName") 
    set @productPrice = field(@row,"ProductPrice") 

]%%

Product row %%=v(@i)=%%, product name is %%=v(@productName)=%%, product price is %%=v(@productPrice)=%%

%%[ next @i ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

These are the error messages I get:

[image: Error messages]

If anyone has any experience, all help is appreciated.

Comment: For information, you don't need to declare a variable in AMPScript. You can directly SET it to whatever you want.

Comment: Tested it inside my own environment inside an html block and the code is working

Comment: Same thing on my side. It's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wrote this script inside a text area and not inside HTML or codeblocks. Thats why everything is transformed/encoded into html. For example your newlines are now a `<br>` and your " now may even be `&quot;` Because you actually do not have a `<br>` between your code and i believe it should be working.

Atleast the code works for me when i changed it to my environment (other identifier and dataextensions)

Comment: I agree looking at the code and the error it appears there is some character after var @lookup  two options take it to notepad or just remove it